# Herokuにpushできない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

#### 背景

某スクールでの課題に取り組んでおります。
スクールメンターに質問しすぎて嫌がられており、メンターからの返答が雑になってきているので、更にわかりにくくなっています。
ですので、こちらで質問させてください。

ECサイトを作る中で、AWS S3とHerokuを連携させる環境構築を行なっております。

#### 現状

環境構築の過程において

`git push heroku （ブランチ名):master -f` 実行後エラーが出ます。

※ローカル、リモート、Herokuの更新に差異がある為、pushできないということはわかってはおり、強制Pushをしております。

#### 今出ているエラー

```
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: e4d8a765c2478440e424bb07caa43f2f7b8bc
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version e4d8a765c2478440e424bb07caa43f2f7b8bc
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
```

#### 前提

GitHubのMasterのブランチにはpushしてはならないというのが課題の制約です。
何度かやり直す過程で過去のHerokuアプリ削除、過去のブランチ削除を行いました。

#### 参考にしたサイト、実際にやってみたこと

エラー文にある `git push heroku <branchname>:main` を実行
同じエラーが出ます。

#### 実現したいこと

エラーの解消
Herokuへ正常にデプロイしたい

#### 参考画像

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

初学者質問でお恥ずかしい限りですが、皆様のお知恵を拝借したく、どうかご助言ご助力の程、よろしくお願いします

database.yml内容を以下記載します

```
# MySQL. Versions 5.0 and up are supported.
#
# Install the MySQL driver
#   gem install mysql2
#
# Ensure the MySQL gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'mysql2'
#
# And be sure to use new-style password hashing:
#   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/old-client.html

default: &default
 adapter: mysql2
 encoding: utf8
 collation: utf8_general_ci
 pool: 5
 host: <%= ENV['MYSQL_HOST'] || 'localhost' %>
 username: <%= ENV['MYSQL_USERNAME'] || 'root' %>
 password: <%= ENV['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] || '' %>
 socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

development:
 <<: *default
 database: potepanec_2_7_development

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
 <<: *default
 database: potepanec_2_7_test

# As with config/secrets.yml, you never want to store sensitive information,
# like your database password, in your source code. If your source code is
# ever seen by anyone, they now have access to your database.
#
# Instead, provide the password as a unix environment variable when you boot
# the app. Read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database
# for a full rundown on how to provide these environment variables in a
# production deployment.
#
# On Heroku and other platform providers, you may have a full connection URL
# available as an environment variable. For example:
#
#   DATABASE_URL="mysql2://myuser:mypass@localhost/somedatabase"
#
# You can use this database configuration with:
#
#   production:
#     url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
#
production:
 <<: *default
 url: <%= ENV['JAWSDB_URL']&.sub('mysql://', 'mysql2://') %>
```

Comment: pushで失敗なのは大枠では正解なんですが、正しくはprecompileで失敗しているようです。
herokuは実行環境なので、pushして実行できるようにするまでのprocessのどこかで失敗したら全部pushできませんでした。となります。
error logを見るとYAMLのsyntax errorが出ているようですが、このアプリはlocal環境で動作しますか？

Comment: 豚トロ様
返信遅れまして申し訳ありません。
ローカルではdocker経由で動作します。
（貴殿の質問に対する回答として合ってますでしょうか？）

Comment: docker使って環境作って、そこでは動作してるってことですね。
では、その実行環境はdevelopmentで動作してますか？productionで動作してますか？
herokuでは、defaultでproduction動作になります。
その差異が原因かもしれません。また、database.ymlでsyntax errorが出てるのは明らかですので、そちらも確認が必要ですね。差し支えなければ、database.ymlを転記すると良い回答が得られるかもしれません。

Comment: 豚トロ様
ご連絡ありがとうございます。
ご指摘事項前半はこちらで一旦確認致します。
後半のdatabaseに関しては
エラー文に１２行目以降に問題があると書かれておりますので、まずは１２行周へんをここに記載します。

default: &default
 adapter: mysql2
 encoding: utf8
 collation: utf8_general_ci
 pool: 5
 host: <%= ENV['MYSQL_HOST'] || 'localhost' %>
 username: <%= ENV['MYSQL_USERNAME'] || 'root' %>
 password: <%= ENV['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] || '' %>
 socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

Comment: database.ymlの内容を質問に追記しました

Comment: 豚トロ様
当案件無事にデプロイすることができました。
親身にアドバイスいただきありがとうございます。
今後ともよろしくお願いします

Comment: 解決したのでしたら、問題の原因とその解決方法を回答に記載していただけたら幸いです。